# How to get an image to move up and down with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Using html and javascript, i create variables in js to corrospond to the buttons i made in html, they are to make an image move left, right, up, and down.

the image move left and right just fine but i can't seem to get it to move up or down. i thought it should work similary to moving it left and right but it doesnt seem to work.

here is the code i have

```
leftButton.addEventListener("click", moveLeft);
    rightButton.addEventListener("click", moveRight);
    downButton.addEventListener("click", moveDown);


    rocketPicture.style.position = "relative";
    rocketPicture.style.left = '0px';

    function moveLeft(){
      rocketPicture.style.left = parseInt(rocketPicture.style.left ) - 10 + 'px';
      }
    function moveRight(){
      rocketPicture.style.left = parseInt(rocketPicture.style.left ) + 10 + 'px';
    }

    function moveDown(){
      rocketPicture.style.top = parseInt(rocketPicture.style.top) + 10 + 'px';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned an initial value - 0 - for `style.left`, but not for `style.top`, hence checking its value gives `undefined`.

Now, `parseInt(undefined)` returns `NaN`, and doing anything mathematical with `NaN` just puts more `NaN` in this world.

Solution: assign an initial value for `style.top` in the same way you did for `style.left`.

---

As a sidenote, it might be worthwhile to unify all those move functions in the same step func, like this:

```
function move(dir, delta) {
  const prev = parseInt( rocketPicture.style[dir] );
  // assert !Number.isNaN(prev)
  rocketPicture.style[dir] = prev + delta + 'px'; 
}

function moveUp() { move('top', -10) }
function moveDown() { move('top', 10) }
function moveLeft() { move('left', -10) }
function moveRight() { move('left', 10) }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Sometimes everything gets so jumbled up I overlook the smallest things! This helped give more meaning to my code and allow me to understand more of what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Element#getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) ? It provides information regarding your element including its `top` and `left` position without having to convert the values with `parseInt`.

It looks something like this:

```
{
  "x": 50,
  "y": 100,
  "width": 124,
  "height": 119.19999694824219,
  "top": 100,
  "right": 174,
  "bottom": 219.1999969482422,
  "left": 50
}
```

Working solution:

```js
const box = document.getElementById("item");

function vertical(value){
  const {top} = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  box.style.top = `${top + value}px`;
}

function horizontal(value){
  const {left} = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  box.style.left = `${left + value}px`;
}
```

```css
#item {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  left: 50px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="item">
  box
</div>
<button onclick="vertical(-10)">Up</button>
<button onclick="vertical(10)">Down</button>
<button onclick="horizontal(-10)">Left</button>
<button onclick="horizontal(10)">Right</button>
```